# Remove phone from Magento Admin > Customer > Manage Customer > Address

Tags: magento, backend

I want to remove the field PHONE and FAX from the Magento customer administration. I already removed all the fields and validations in the frontend, but this field is still in the backend

Thanks!

Comment: you have to edit code on the path for adminhtml too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete them from DB. 
Table eav_attribute.
Check entity_type_id firstly - it need to belong to customer_address;

```
SELECT entity_type_id FROM `eav_entity_type` WHERE entity_type_code = 'customer_address'
DELETE from eav_attribute where attribute_code IN ('telephone', 'fax') AND entity_type_id = ? (from previous query)
```

No code changes will be needed then.

Backup your DB firstly.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the validation in the admin form? magento will no more look for the missing telephone?

Comment: yes. validation of these fields is dynamic, based on DB settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment out the relevant lines of code in Adminhtml folder on approperiate place, suggesting you as for the front end , you already have done this, so  let the exact path on you

rather then deleting from db, a better way would be commenting the relevant lines of code. as if something goes wrong, Mag will reload the db from the default script and the fields you deleted will appear again..

HTH...

Comment: In the frontend, comment the code was not enough. I needed to remove some validation from core too. Do you know how can I remove the validation from the admin form?

Answer (score 0):

Not much effort is required , just run these SQL commands

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute`
```

Now look for `Telephone` under `attribute_code`, mostly its with `attribute_id` 31

Update the table using the following SQL statement

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = '0' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` =31;
```